# Azure Pipelines failing at NuGet Restore stage

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am using the Image vs2017-win2016 for the Build and as part of the Build, I have the Nuget Restore task which is failing with the below error message. Can someone tell me what went wrong here and how we can fix it up? It's a simple Asp.Net Web App.

```
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6036745Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6136450Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6136733Z Task         : NuGet
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6137224Z Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6137701Z Version      : 2.179.0
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6138100Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6138522Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
2021-06-25T09:01:16.6138831Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-25T09:01:17.3136968Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2021-06-25T09:01:17.4377830Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2021-06-25T09:01:17.8046121Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2021-06-25T09:01:17.8104107Z Active code page: 65001
2021-06-25T09:01:17.8631847Z Detected NuGet version 4.4.1.4656 / 4.4.1
2021-06-25T09:01:17.8642220Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2021-06-25T09:01:17.8812714Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name NuGetOrg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_31.config
2021-06-25T09:01:19.1590360Z Package Source with Name: NuGetOrg added successfully.
2021-06-25T09:01:19.1660433Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\1\s\VSDemoPipeline.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_31.config
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4269841Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\a\1\s\VSDemoPipeline\VSDemoPipeline.csproj]
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4271151Z 
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4279527Z NuGet Version: 4.4.1.4656
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4280682Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4281803Z MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4283437Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\4rucjvrx.krk.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\opqnszhe.dir.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="D:\a\1\s" /p:RestoreConfigFile="D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_31.config" /p:SolutionDir="D:\a\1\s"
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4289820Z NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4334578Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.<GetProjectReferencesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4335343Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4335807Z    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4336289Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4336788Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4337172Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4337555Z    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4337950Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4339708Z    at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4855912Z ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\a\1\s\VSDemoPipeline\VSDemoPipeline.csproj])
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4866755Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore
2021-06-25T09:01:47.4877131Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have APS.NET app built on NET Core 3.1 or higher, use `windows-latest` agent in Azure DevOps.

Older version of the agents do not support it and it is also evident from the error if you notice.

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\a\1\s\VSDemoPipeline\VSDemoPipeline.csproj])
> 2021-06-25T09:01:47.4866755Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore

In the pipeline make sure you have "Use Dotnet Core" task with appropriate version:

[image: Use Dotnet Core Task]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am using a Classic Pipeline and Under Agent Specification I don't find "Windows-latest", I only find windows-2019 but it also doesn't work. Any idea why I don't see windows-latest under Agent Specification?

Comment: Yes indeed that classic pipelines seem to have windows-2019. 

In your pipeline did you add "Use .NET core" task with version filled correctly?